# Screenshot in part of UIView masked to UIBezierPath / CGPath

Tags: swift, mask, uibezierpath, cgpath

I'm building a drawing application. I'm drawing using `CGMutablePath`.
I want the user to be able to select a part of the drawn paths and then move that part, like this:

[image: selection demo]

I thought, a possible solution would be to mask a view to the drawn area and then take a screenshot in that view.
In here, you can see the area drawn in which I want to take a screenshot:

[image: selecting an area]

To take the screenshot, I get the `last` path drawn, being the area the screenshot is to be taken in:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = last.closedPath // returns CGPath.closeSubpath()
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
```

I then create an `overlayView` that's the view I'm taking the screenshot in.

```
let overlayView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
overlayView.backgroundColor = .black
overlayView.alpha = 0.4
view.addSubview(overlayView)
view.bringSubview(toFront: overlayView)
```

I'm then masking the view to the path:

```
overlayView.mask(withPath: UIBezierPath(cgPath: last.closedPath!))
```

The `.mask(withPath:)` method comes from here:

```
extension UIView {
    func mask(withPath path: UIBezierPath) {
        let path = path
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Then, I take the screenshot in `overlayView`:

```
let image: UIImage = {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(overlayView.bounds.size, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    drawView.drawHierarchy(in: overlayView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
}()

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

What happens, is that the `overlayView` has the screen's full size and also draws the screenshot in the full size.
When debugging the view hierarchy, I can also see that the `overlayView` is still full-size, not masked to the path.

So, instead of getting only the part drawn around as screenshot, I get an image of the whole view / screen.

#### Question

How do I successfully mask the view to the drawn area so I can take a screenshot in that part of the screen only?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `overlayView.frame` equals `self.view.frame`, which is why the image is being taken full screen.

A solution to your issue may be solved as follows (although I may have understood incorrectly):

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = last.closedPath // returns CGPath.closeSubpath()
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
let rect = shapeLayer.path.boundingBoxOfPath

let overlayView = UIView(frame: rect)
```

Comment: Hey Pranav, I tried that, but it still saves a screenshot of the full screen. Also, I can't just use the bounding box because the area drawn will be round or something, so I need those rounded corners to be respected too.

Comment: Ok. I think the issue may be with the `drawView` frame in that case. Hmm. Maybe worth debugging and printing the frames of each layer in the process; I haven't reproduced your app, so not entirely sure about it.

Comment: Would you want to look into it if I shared it with you?

Comment: I'd like to help, but I might not be able to solve the issue. ( don't have a lot of spare time nowadays). I'd be happy to try though if you're able to share a basic demo? Either way, no worries!

Comment: Thanks anyway. I might ask you again about this :)

Comment: Ok. :) By the way in UIGraphicsBeginImageContext maybe try setting third argument to 1?